# How can I upload Array of objects to api with MultipartRequest in flutter?

Tags: flutter, file-upload, multipart

[I should upload these type of data to api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKwhw.png)

How to upload Array of objects using MultipartRequest? Object should consist of {"image" : image}

```
{
  "files: [
     {"image" : "fileeeeeee"},
     {"image" : "fileeeeeee"},
     {"image" : "fileeeeeee"},
  ],
  "title": "string",
  "owner": id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example project about data with images(file) with Dio.

you can find the demo form - https://youtu.be/Zhd4uBEkXBk
source code - https://github.com/Sameera-Perera/Flutter-image-upload-complete-example